# Using mouse wheel to scroll while hovering over textbox in Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have not had any luck in attempting to search for this.
Curious if it is possible to use the scroll wheel on a mouse, while hovering over a textbox in a GUI, not while the textbox has focus.  I am using WinForms, maybe its possible in WPF?

Here is the current code for my textbox:

```
$textboxResults = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxResults.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(300,378)#585,378
$textboxResults.Location = New-Object Drawing.Size @(30,165)#64,143
$textboxResults.Multiline = $true
$textboxResults.TabStop = $false
$textboxResults.ReadOnly = $true
$textboxResults.ScrollBars = "Both"
```

Comment: You can use the scroll wheel all you want, but what is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If I click in the textbox, I can use the mouse wheel to scroll up and down, yes.  I am wondering if there's a way to scroll up and down in the textbox WITHOUT clicking in the textbox, just by hovering the mouse over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original question it was asked if the desired behavior could be accomplished without giving the text box focus. I was not able to accomplish that however in the comment the OP asks if there is a way to

> ...scroll up and down in the textbox WITHOUT clicking ... just by
>   hovering the mouse over...

I am going to assume that you don't care whether the text box has focus, but that you do not want to click to give focus. With that assumption here is my solution:

First we need to create a custom mousehover event for the text box (or boxes) in question that will give the box focus:

```
function textBoxMouseHover(){
     $this.focus()
}
```

Please note that the use of $this to refer to the sending object is version specific. I do not think it will work before powershell v2.

Next we need to add this event to our text boxes:

```
$myTextBox.add_mousehover({textBoxMouseHover})
```

That's it. Hovering over a textbox with this event attached will give the box focus and you can immediately use the mouse wheel to scroll. You can attach this event to as many text boxes as you like. As for doing this without focus, I'm afraid I'm not skilled enough to do that.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  I see now my fixation on the word focus may have been misleading(poor overall understanding on my part). I tested this out on my script/app and it works exactly as I hoped. Thank you!